# Right click shortcut menu code locks shared database every time

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, office365

I have a compiled Access database with a front-end (where this code is running) and compiled back end data storage.

I have code to create a shortcut menu, if inserted into the start-up routine of the database, MS Access ignores the default setting to open as shared mode on the Access database, and opens as Exclusive mode. This is causing a lot of problems.

```
Public Sub sbCreateReportShortCutMenu()

Dim cmbRightClick as Office.CommandBar

Set cmbRightClick =  CommandBars.Add("cmdFormRightClick", 0,, True)
Set cmbRightClick = Nothing

End Sub
```

Moving the code so it only runs when needed (before opening forms in this case), the issue still occurs.  If the first user in the database opens a form which requires this code, and nobody else is in the database at the time, the database goes in to exclusive mode and other people can't access it.

All PCs/people accessing the database front end have Access set to shared/no locks as default.

What is it about this code causing the shared database to lock? Any ideas please? Thank you in advance

Comment: Where does the `CommandBars` object come from?

Comment: command bars interface I believe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.commandbars?view=office-pia

Comment: This is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.add -- For a shortcut menu you need `msoBarPopup = 5` instead of 0 as second parameter. (No idea if this will solve the lock.)

Comment: Also note that all users should have their own frontend installed locally. Don't use a shared frontend. This will solve lots of issues.

Answer (score 1):

`CommandBars` were deprecated. You need to use the Fluent UI for customizing Office UI. Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: That's true, commandbars are deprecated, however the commandbar gives access to the 'right click' shortcut menu. The ribbon does not create a new right click shortcut menu as far as I know (I could be wrong).

Surely it won't be causing database lock because it is deprecated?

Comment: The Fluent UI allows customizing context menus as well. Not sure about the lock. CommandBars are left for executing built-in controls programmatically.